# SearchResultItem POCO not populated

Tags: content-search, azure-search

I have a class (SBJSearchItem) that inherits SearchResultItem that I'm using with the ContentSearchManager.  The problem is that some of my SBJSearchItem properties are not populating. I'm using Azure Search as part of Sitecore Azure PaaS.

```
public class SBJSearchItem : SearchResultItem
{
    #region Public Properities

    // Type is working. This stores an ID and comes back as a string, which is fine.
    [IndexField("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    // Authors is working. This stores a list of IDs.
    [IndexField("authors")]
    public string Authors { get; set; }

    // Title is working. It stores a string.
    [IndexField("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    /*
    Publish Date does not work. This is just a date/time field in Sitecore.
    It is stored as a string type in the index. I made it nullable because
    I get an error that says that it cannot convert null to DataTime.
    I believe that's because it also pulls the template which doesn't have
    a date set.
    */
    [IndexField("publish_date")]
    public DateTime? PublishDate { get; set; }

    // Section does not work. It is a computed field that I set to a string.
    [IndexField("section")]
    public string Section { get; set; }

    /*
    DateSearch does not work. This is a computed field. It is stored as a 
    DateTimeOffset type. I get a DateTime.MinValue.
    */
    // EDIT: Added this per comments
    [TypeConverter(typeof(IndexFieldDateTimeValueConverter))]
    [IndexField("date_search")]
    public DateTime DateSearch { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

**Edit 4**
Apparently getting the index in the manner that I was doesn't work the same as getting the index specifically by name.

Here's an example of how I'm executing the query:

```
// Be careful if you use the commented lines here:
//var indexableItem = new SitecoreIndexableItem(currentStory);
//var index = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(indexableItem);

// This apparently is DIFFERENT than the previous index declaration above
var index = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_master_index");

using (var context = index.CreateSearchContext())
{
    var query = context.GetQueryable<SBJSearchItem>()
                .Where(i => i.TemplateId == SitecoreItemIds.BLOG_STORY_TEMPLATE
                    && i.ItemId == currentStory.ID)
                .ToList();
}
```

The query works except those few properties that I mentioned above are null in my list of items (well one item in this case).

Here's my patch that adds the computed fields into the index.  I have verified that the values are actually in the index.

```
      <index id="sitecore_master_index">
        <configuration>
          <!-- EDIT: Added per comments -->
          <fieldMap type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.FieldMaps.CloudFieldMap, Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure">
            <fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
              <field type="System.String"   fieldName="section"     cloudFieldName="section"     boost="1f" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.CloudSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure"/>
              <field type="System.DateTime" fieldName="date_search" cloudFieldName="date_search" boost="1f" format="yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.CloudSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure"/>
            </fieldNames>
          </fieldMap>
          <!-- END EDIT -->
          <fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">
            <field fieldName="section" storageType="yes" indexType="tokenized">
              SBJSitecore.Components.Editorial.SectionComputedField,SBJSitecore
            </field>
            <field fieldName="date_search" storageType="yes" indexType="tokenized" type="System.DateTime">
              SBJSitecore.Components.Editorial.DateSearchComputedField,SBJSitecore
            </field>
          </fields>
        </configuration>
      </index>
```

**EDIT 2**

Per comments added my Computed fields into the Map.  Reindex and tried again. Still not returning

```
<cloudTypeMapper type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Schema.CloudSearchTypeMapper, Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure" patch:source="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Index.SectionField.config">
    <maps hint="raw:AddMap" patch:source="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Index.SectionField.config">
        <map type="System.Char" cloudType="Edm.String"/>
        <map type="System.String" cloudType="Edm.String"/>
        <map type="System.Guid" cloudType="Edm.String"/>
        <map type="System.Int32" cloudType="Edm.Int32"/>
        <map type="System.Int64" cloudType="Edm.Int64"/>
        <map type="System.Double" cloudType="Edm.Double"/>
        <map type="System.Single" cloudType="Edm.Double"/>
        <map type="System.Boolean" cloudType="Edm.Boolean"/>
        <map type="System.DateTime" cloudType="Edm.DateTimeOffset"/>
        <map type="System.DateTimeOffset" cloudType="Edm.DateTimeOffset"/>
        <map type="System.String[]" cloudType="Collection(Edm.String)"/>
        <map type="System.Guid[]" cloudType="Collection(Edm.String)"/>
        <map type="System.Int32[]" cloudType="Collection(Edm.String)"/>
        <map type="System.Object[]" cloudType="Collection(Edm.String)"/>
        <map type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.IIndexableId, Sitecore.ContentSearch" cloudType="Edm.String"/>
        <map type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.IIndexableUniqueId, Sitecore.ContentSearch" cloudType="Edm.String"/>
        <map type="Sitecore.Data.ID, Sitecore.Kernel" cloudType="Edm.String"/>
        <map type="Sitecore.Data.ItemUri, Sitecore.Kernel" cloudType="Edm.String"/>
        <map type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemId, Sitecore.ContentSearch" cloudType="Edm.String"/>
        <map type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemUniqueId, Sitecore.ContentSearch" cloudType="Edm.String"/>
        <map type="Sitecore.Marketing.Taxonomy.Model.TaxonUri, Sitecore.Marketing.Taxonomy" cloudType="Edm.String"/>
        <map type="Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.TaxonomicClassification, Sitecore.Marketing" cloudType="Edm.String"/>
        <!-- Patched these values in -->
        <map type="SBJSitecore.Components.Editorial.SectionComputedField,SBJSitecore" cloudType="Edm.String" patch:source="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Index.SectionField.config"/>
        <map type="SBJSitecore.Components.Editorial.DateSearchComputedField,SBJSitecore" cloudType="Edm.DateTimeOffset" patch:source="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Index.SectionField.config"/>
        <!-- End Patch -->
    </maps>
</cloudTypeMapper>
```

Snippit of the index:

```
"value": [
    {
        "date_search": "2017-02-14T17:23:00Z",
        "publish_date": "20170214T122300",
    }
]
```

**EDIT**

I made a couple of edits per comments.  Neither of these changes seem to have any impact.  I am in touch with Sitecore support on this issue.

I also noticed that the CreatedDate & Updated fields are DateTime.MinValue on my search results (`var query` above).

Comment: Im noticing that you are using "sitecore_master_index", Is your item in your search query also coming from master database?

Comment: It is. I do intend on using a custom index at some point, but for now this is in master.

Comment: I would start by looking at a functional DateTime property in the Sitecore.ContentSearch.SearchTypes.SearchResultItem Type (CreatedDate, Updated) and its related configuration (AddComputedIndexField, AddFieldByFieldName) with /sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx. Make sure that the index you're using has the correct definition of the field in its schema. You can also try decorating the POCO property with a TypeConverter attribute since the value is in the index as a string: [TypeConverter(typeof(IndexFieldDateTimeValueConverter))]

Comment: Try adding your computed fields in the fieldmap as well. With storageType and indexType, but make sure to use the correct syntax - check the default config for Azure Search as this is different from the Lucene one (used in the answers below).

Comment: @IsNull Good suggestions. I updated my question reflecting the changes, but alas no better.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/supported-data-types 
It looks like there's no actual DateTime type in Azure Search...
Perhaps you can change all of the datetime fields to strings and do the parsing in code?

Comment: @IsNull There is a DateTimeOffset type which is what CreatedDate & Updated use as well as what's used for my DateSearch field.

Comment: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/search_and_indexing/configure_azure_search 

See the Map Fields section: 

"Note You must define the map element for all custom fields like this: 
<map type="<Field type>" cloudType="<Edm type from list of supported types>" />"

Comment: @IsNull Still not working as expected.

Comment: That's no good. Well, considering that the system datetime fields are also not functioning properly this sounds like a bug in Sitecores Azure Search implementation. The next step is probably a Sitecore Support ticket. You can always decompile their assemblies into your own code and debugging it to see what is going on in there.

Comment: @IsNull I submitted a ticket yesterday afternoon. Hopefully they'll have a good response.

Comment: @Kevin can you please share the output of an index's schema and example of one document where the above code doesn't work?

Comment: To get schema call this Azure Search REST API in Postman: https://[search service name].search.windows.net/indexes/sitecore-master-index/?api-‌​version=2016-09-01

Comment: To get a particular document by an item's ID, call this one: https://[search service name].search.windows.net/indexes/sitecore-master-index/docs?‌​api-version=2016-09-‌​01&search=[currentSt‌​ory.ID]&searchFields‌​=path_1

Comment: You have to authorize both requests by adding the 'api-key' header w/ admin key value, which you can take in Azure portal under the Keys section when stain on 'Azure Search' blade of a particular instance.

Comment: Closing. Will reopen if resolution from Sitecore Support is recorded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When getting the index it seems like it is better to call an index by name

I was calling the index like so:

```
var indexableItem = new SitecoreIndexableItem(currentStory);
var index = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(indexableItem);
```

But it didn't work as expected.

So I changed it to this:

```
var index = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_master_index");
```

And it works properly.

Comment: I had the same issue and this was the fix

Answer (score 0):

Add a date mask in the configuration:

`<field fieldName="pubdate" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.DateTime" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" format="yyyyMMdd" />`

Comment: I looked at the other fields in ShowConfig and replicated them. This didn't help any.  I also noticed that the system date/time fields are not working. Seems to be a Sitecore bug.

Answer (score 0):

Let me summary the outcome of this issue, in case somebody will face it in the future.

#### Field #1

`` [IndexField("publish_date")]`
public DateTime PublishDate { get; set; } ``

In an index's schema, the `publish_date` field was defined as `Edm.String` date type, like shown below:

`{
  "@odata.context": "https://[search-service-name].search.windows.net/$metadata#indexes/$entity",
  "@odata.etag": "\"0x1B38DCC03076AB8\"",
  "name": "sitecore-master-index",
  "fields": [
   ...
   {
     "name": "publish_date",
     "type": "Edm.String",
     ...
   },
  ...
  ],
  ...
}`

A value was stored in the same format as Sitecore keeps it when viewing `Raw Values`:

`{
  "@odata.context": "...",
  "value": [
    {
      ...
      "publish_date": "20161208T073400",
      ...
    }
  ]
}`

As a result, when Sitecore tried populating an instance of a POCO class, it caused the following exception:

`System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'.`

**Solutions:**

1. In a POCO class, change type from the `DateTime` to `string`.

OR

2. In an index schema, change type from the `Edm.String` to `Edm.DateTimeOffset`.

#### Field #2

`[IndexField("section")]
public string Section { get; set; }`

If an index'a document has no value, then an instance of a POCO class will have no value either.

`{
  "@odata.context": "...",
  "value": [
    {
      ...
      "section": null,
      ...
    }
  ]
}`

**Solution**

1. Get a document from an index and check whether it has any value or not.

#### Field #3

`[IndexField("date_search")]
public DateTime DateSearch { get; set; }`

When calling the `ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(IIndexable indexable)` method, Sitecore triggers the `contentSearch.getContextIndex` pipeline to resolve an index name.

`<contentSearch.getContextIndex patch:source="Sitecore.ContentSearch.config">
  <processor type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Pipelines.GetContextIndex.FetchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />`

While calling the `ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(string name)` one, you directly say which index you want to use.

**Solution:**

1. When using the `ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(new SitecoreIndexableItem(item))` method, check what you have in the above pipeline to make sure there is no custom processor that might change the default behavior.

**NB:**
There is [REST API for Azure Search](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/), which you can use to get data from your index before map it on an instance of a POCO class.

Additionally, [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) is my favorite tool when I need to work with any REST API

Best Wishes, Oleg